# Debugging not being able to see what I type in bash

Tags: bash

I keep not being able to see what I'm typing in bash. The prompt appears and I can still run commands but I'm typing them blind.

This happens on multiple OSes (both KDE/konsole, ubuntu 14.04 and fedora 26). It's often after a <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>, but very intermittent. It must be related to one or many of the scripts I use and I want to know how I can debug what is happening. `stty sane` fixes the terminal, but this happens many times a day. I've tried emptying my `PS1` and `PROMPT_COMMAND` variables and it doesn't seem to be them.

1. What is actually happening to make text invisible?
2. How can I narrow down the cause?

Answer (score 4):

First, you can fix this with

```
stty echo
```

(and, of course, `man stty`).

One of your scripts has a flaw, in that it turns off character echo, but fails to turn it on (in `bash`, via the `trap` buitin).

In the Early Days (1967), computer access was via remote terminals like the TeleType ASR-35 and KSR-33, at a speed of 110 Baud.

There were two ways of sending characters to the computer on the other end: Half Duplex, where characters were echoed locally, and probably sent to the computer; and Full Duplex, where characters were not echoed locally, but sent to the computer, which echoed each character back to the terminal, allowing verification.

Letting the computer (running Unix in 1970) know which way your TeleType was configured was done via `stty -echo` and `stty echo` (see `man stty`).

`stty echo` is included in `stty sane`. `stty sane` never hurts.

The Unix "tty" concept is still in use with your terminal today.